# Implement a dynamic dropdown menu based on on the number of lines of text file

Tags: python, dynamic, drop-down-menu, tkinter

I am trying to achieve a dropdown which changes dynamically based on the number of lines of text file.
I can find the number of lines using:

```
with open('Cipher 3.5 Output.txt') as f:
    Line_Count = (sum(1 for _ in f))
```

What I am then trying to do is make the dropdown have an option for each line in the file, for example if the file has three lines the dropdown will have the options 1, 2 and 3.

I am trying to achieve this so that in my encryption program the user can choose which line of their encrypted text file to read and decrypt.

Currently my interface looks like this:
[image]

I am planning to add a label between Key2 and Output which reads 'Choose line' or something to that effect, and then a dropdown box between the two Entry boxes. Finally I will add a button between the Random Key and Clear buttons which will set the line number to 'all' and read the whole file.

So, how can I implement the dynamically changing dropdown? Your help is appreciated.

I very much doubt you'll need it but see [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4wRmT4UEC2IbnIxd194eHgxVnM/view?usp=sharing) for the rest of my code.

Comment: Are the contents of the file changing dynamically so that you have to update the _dropdown menu_ or the contents remain the same for the whole duration of the program?

Comment: The contents will change each time the user hits encrypt. A new line will be added to the .txt file.

Comment: Ok. Is it ok to use a `Combobox`?

Comment: So yes, the dropdown menu has to be updated while the program is running, meaning that I will probably have to make the code for finding the number of lines into a function and run it after the user hits encrypt (In the function called when the button is pressed)

Comment: Yes. ComboBox should work the same way

Comment: If you need more help, just comment under my answer, so that I see the notification ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [*ttk.Combobox*](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Combobox.html) to let the user choose a line and you can associate a *command* with the click of the Button `Encrypt`. In this command (function) you will put the code that calculates the lines and you will update there the values of the `ttk.Combobox`. If you are using Python 3 (I hope), you can import the *ttk.Combobox* in the following way:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
```

Comboboxes are part of the *tkinter* extension *ttk*, you have explicitly to say you want to import from that module.

If you are using Python 2, you can simply import from ttk:

```
from ttk import Combobox
```

Now, suppose the following is the code for the Button `Encrypt`:

```
encrypt = Button(master, text='Encrypt')
```

Then you can associate a command with the click of a Button in the following way:

```
encrypt = Button(master, text='Encrypt', command=on_click) # without ( )
```

Now, you can define the function `on_click`:

```
def on_click():
     # calculate the lines
     # update the values of the Combobox
```

Comment: I'm feeling really stpid right now, but Combobox doesn't appear to be part of tkinter whether I spell t Combobox, combobox or ComboBox. ttk isn't recognised as a module in python 3.4 either

Comment: I understand that, as I have already used it in my buttons, however I can' seem to get a Combobox through the same method, Item_Name = Combobox(root, values= ...

Comment: What do you mean _I can'seem to get a Combobox through the same method_? That you cannot access the combobox reference? If so, you can use `global combobox_reference` at the beginning of the command, so that you tell Python you are referring to the global reference `combobox_reference`, if combobox_reference is a global variable. If `combobox_reference` is not a global variable, you have to make it, or use OOP paradigm.

Comment: I mean I can't get python to recognize Combobox as part of the Tkinter module.

Comment: For every other item I just write Button1 = Button(root, stuff...)

Comment: But python throws an error when I write Combobox instead of Button

Comment: @TheoPearson-Bray Have you seen my edited answer? You have to import from `ttk` explicitly.

Comment: ttk isn't a module according to my python (3.4) and I already have 'from tkinter import *  ' at the top of my code, tkinter and ttk are the same right??

Comment: Ok, I said I was being stupid. And I was, ttk is part of tkinter and I thought it was imported when I imported * from tkinter. I have it working now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70163/discussion-between-theo-pearson-bray-and-rinzler).